# C# WPF - ScrollViewer + Label troubles

Tags: wpf, xaml, label, scrollview

I tried to make a scrollveiwer with my label.

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
       <Label Name="LabelData" MaxHeight="272" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

MaxHeihgt for my Label has to be 272, as long as bigger value goes out of my Grid.
Could you help me ?

Comment: Set the `MaxHeight` on your ScrollViewer, not the Label. The Label should be allowed to grow as large as it needs to, and when it grows larger than the ScrollViewer the scrollbar will appear

Comment: I posted it as an answer instead. I didn't before because I wasn't entirely clear on what the question was :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `MaxHeight` on your ScrollViewer, not the Label.

The Label should be allowed to grow as large as it needs to, and when it grows larger than the ScrollViewer, the scrollbar will appear.